# Random row from big query result

Tags: mysql, random, row

I need to get 1-2 rows from query result retrived with SQL select on indexed columns without getting the whole record set.

For example I will retrieve 10 000 records using query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field 1>1 AND field1 < 10
```

but I need only 1 random row from this query regarding to highload of my database.

I can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field 1>1 AND field1 < 10 LIMIT 100, 1
```

But I don't know records numebr to use correct offset range

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: There are lots of ideas here: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0):

You could use ORDER BY RAND()

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 > 1 AND field1 < 10 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This will return 1 random row with field1 in between 1 and 10

Comment: On database with 10kk records you will down your server and loose all users ;-)

Comment: Thats true. Then you will need to use two queries like described in this article: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: count(*) not a variant on big mysql query results, it will take some seconds to calculate calc(*) with WHERE on 1kk row table. I have some ideas, but I'm not sure in their correctness yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about restricting the records you select in the first place?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IN (CONVERT(RAND()*10,SIGNED),CONVERT(RAND()*10,SIGNED)) LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I have criteria on field1 how can I choose it rand?

Comment: if the criteria is a range, you can create a random number that would fall in that range

Comment: but there are many rows within this selection even when I've choosen criteria and I should take not first but random row. Anyway thank you've pushed me on interesting idea also.