# How do I display random text and image from PHP form on refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I'm a fairly new programmer and I'm currently working on creating a program for a web-based art exhibit that would will display a random image and text using data from a PHP form which requires inputs for both.

I will need to create a PHP form that gathers text and a picture from the visitor.
Example PHP page:

```
*What is your name?* = Max

*Upload photo.* = pic.jpg
```

The finished project would be a webpage that - on refresh - would display the image and the text gathered from the PHP form randomly. So on refresh the page would display a random text input (I.E Max, Alan, Mark, etc.) and a random picture (I.E pic.jpg, pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg) I'm guessing from a MySQL database.

The page, on refresh, would therefore display something like this:

```
Max / pic.jpg

REFRESH

Alan / pic3.jpg

REFRESH

Mark / pic2.jpg
```

And so on...

This is what I have so far:

```
    <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name'];  
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("mysite.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$name', '$pic')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: There is 2 ways - `RAND` in `SQL` query or `rand` in `php` after you've extracted both name/pic data arrays from database. Yes, it should be in database.

Comment: Here's [php's `rand()` documentation](http://us3.php.net/rand)

Comment: Thank you, @grimv01k . I assumed it should be kept in a database.
What should the PHP form and HTML page look like code wise then?

Comment: For the names, I'd go with `echo array_rand(['Mike', 'John', 'Peter']);` if it's a short list. If it's a long, you can either parse it from a file, include another file or fetch it from the database. Please update your question to reflect what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, @FranciscoPresencia - how would I go about creating a PHP form that adds the uploaded picture and submitted text to that list?

Comment: It depends, do you want it to be from ANOTHER visitor or would you write manually the names/pictures?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I would like it to be live so if someone submits the PHP form (image and text) both of those are added to their respective lists automatically, not manually.

Comment: Okay, then you need to go the database route... and that's definitely too long for a simple answer on SO. I'll explain the steps and refer to tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pull out the data using 

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;

Then pull out the 

<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $name=$row['name'];
    $imagename=$row['imagename'];   


//write the logic here use echo or close and open php using <? and ?>
//giving an example

echo "Name: ".$name."<br>";
echo "<img src='directory/'".$imagename." width='100' height='100'>";

//OR other way

?>
Name : <? echo $name;?><br>

<img src="directory/<? echo $imagename;?>" width="100" height="100">


<?

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to create the html form. I assume you have some basic knowledge about this, so let's assume you do it and post it to `post.php`. Here you'll need to:

- Handle the image.
- Insert the name and image reference into the database.
- Redirect the user to the landing page (important to avoid refreshing issues like "want to send your data again?").
- Fetch a random entry for the database and display it to the user on the landing page.

A few tutorials:

- [Upload Images Using PHP](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm).
- [Insert data into database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1943069/938236)
- [Pick up a random record from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9967348/938236) Disclaimer: my own question over 1 year ago

However, it's not a 'trivial' task. It'd take few days to someone familiar with the languages, with someoone who is not maybe 1 week provided you start from the ground up.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and update this question when I've gotten further!

Comment: Glad to help! It's better that you start a new question since it would actually be a new question. You'll also get more visibility and more answers.